# Mysql Max number of Rows Insert and Select at a time

Tags: mysql

What is the max number of records can be written and read from Mysql table at a time ? or max number or read and write at a time?

I suppose the data for read and write can vary. If one is reduced then another may go up. But still give some info on it on per second basis or per minute basis.

I am not looking for an exact answer. I am looking for approx answer. 
Also, for hardware, think of average shared hosting provider.

Comment: This is a very vague question .... define *at a time* .. the records structure .. the table structure .. insert query .. the hardware ... the OS ... the MySQL version .. the day of the week ... What are you trying to do and what do you want to measure ?

Comment: You can define those thinking average servers.

Comment: yes, I talked about concurrent read and write.

Comment: All talked about one way, i.e insert only. I am interested in read and write at same time.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no** limit in mysql itself. However, a limit is placed upon the maximum size of the packet, sent to the server. In case of an INSERT or SELECT, a [COM_QUERY](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Internals_ClientServer_Protocol#COM_QUERY) packet is sent by the underlying implementation.

> The largest possible packet that can be transmitted to or from a MySQL
>   5.5 server or client is 1GB.
>   When the mysqld server receives a packet bigger than
>   **max_allowed_packet** bytes, it issues a Packet too large error and
>   closes the connection. With some clients, you may also get a Lost
>   connection to MySQL server during query error if the communication
>   packet is too large.

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/packet-too-large.html)

When it comes to the number of concurrent read/writes, that depends solely upon the disk in use and the CPU. The faster the mysql server can process queries sent, and faster the read/write speeds, the larger the number of concurrent read-writes.

Comment: Upvoted to the post but looking for more info on concurrent write and read.

Comment: You need to specify the hardware. It depends directly upon server hardware.

Comment: Take for example average shared hosting service provider.